# change rout without reloading previous date angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I show my search result data as below.
[image]

This page URL is "http://localhost:8081/#!/app/sanction-screening".  When user clicking the view button, I showed more data in a another page. View button code is

```
 <a href="#!/app/sanction-screening-view/{{users.id}}"> view</a>
```

After click view button page rout like this "http://localhost:8081/#!/app/sanction-screening-view/1"

In the view page controller i am using below code to access object

```
.config(["$stateProvider",function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state("app.sanction-screening-view", {
        url: "/sanction-screening-view/:id",
        templateUrl:
          "modules/sanction-screening-view/sanction-screening-view.html",
        controller: "sanctionViewCtrl",
    });
},])
```

All functionalities working well. In the second page i added back button. when i click my back button, page rout to the search result page correctly. but search result is cleared(empty table). My back button code like

```
  $scope.goBack = function () {
    $state.go("app.sanction-screening");
  };
```

When I click the back button, I need to show last search result grid. How I do it, if u can please send the small example

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 possible solutions:

1. Whenever you search on the grid page, change the route to store the searched information, i.e. in the query string, something like `.../app/sanction-screening?search=username`. Now, whenever you initialize this grid page (also includes when you go back from the users page), you get the query string from the route and load the search result accordingly.
2. Instead of polluting your route with query string, you store the state of the grid page (i..e search information) in local storage. For eg: you could store in local storage (`key = <your-grid-name>`, `value = <your-grid-states, query-string, search terms, etc>`). Now, same as above, while initializing the grid page, you take these saved data from the local storage, as per your grid name and load the search result accordingly.